# jquery .val() and google closure compiler

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-closure-compiler

I want to select the first option in a  control so I write:

```
$("#MySelect").val($("#MySelect option:first").val());
```

Now go ahead and copy-paste the following into the [google closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home):

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @externs_url http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/contrib/externs/jquery-1.7.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

$("#MySelect").val($("#MySelect option:first").val());
```

You'll get this error:

[image]

I don't see why the compiler is complaining! What's the problem?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You could do this `$("#MySelect").prop("selectedIndex", 0 )​​​​`

Comment: It looks like it's "determined" that the inner `.val()` method could potentially return a type that doesn't match what the outer `.val()` method expects as a parameter. E.g., if it returned a `jQuery` object that would be incorrect - except that of course we know `.val()` only returns a `jQuery` object when called _with_ a parameter so in your code that would never happen for the inner `.val()`...

Comment: You could use `index()` instead of `val()`

Comment: @Esailija: you should mark your comment as an answer; it works.

Comment: I don't think it's really an answer. It's a workaround - but you shouldn't have to change perfectly fine code just to make some tool happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this `$("#MySelect").prop("selectedIndex", 0)​​​​`. It's simpler and passes closure compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the jQuery methods return different types based on the number and type of the input parameters. This behavior is akin to function overloading in a traditional language. However, JavaScript doesn't support traditional function overloading and jQuery mimics the behavior by inspecting the function arguments.

For `.val`, here's how the method would be annotated if function overloading was supported:

```
/** @return {number|string|Array.<string>} */
jQuery.prototype.val = function() {};

/**
 * @param {number|string|Array.<string>|function(number, *)} newVal
 * @return {!jQuery}
 */
jQuery.prototype.val = function(newVal) {};
```

Since there isn't function overloading, the actual signature for `.val` is a combination of both uses:

```
/**
 * @param {(number|string|Array.<string>|function(number, *))=} newVal
 * @return {!jQuery|number|string|Array.<string>|function(number, *)}
 */
jQuery.prototype.val = function(newVal) {};
```

Because of this, if you wish to use the return value of `.val` as the input for a separate call to `.val`, you must type cast the original return value to specify which usage you expect:

```
$("#MySelect").val(
    /** @type {number|string|Array.<string>} */
    ($("#MySelect option:first").val()) //note the extra parens
);
```

This behavior is described in a comment at the top of the jQuery externs file: http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/trunk/contrib/externs/jquery-1.7.js#20